# Importance of Rest Days

Tags: training, jogging, rest

Why are rest days important?

When the weather permits, I jog (or otherwise work-out) every day, but people often tell me I should not, because rest days are important. What is the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[Evidence shows](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1623894) that more than 5 days a week training increases your risk of musculoskeletal injury.

Rest is physically necessary so that the muscles can repair, rebuild and strengthen -- continuous training can actually weaken it. Without sufficient time to repair, the body will continue to breakdown from intensive exercise.

Overtraining often occurs from a lack of recovery time.  Some signs of overtraining are feeling of general malaise, staleness, depression, decreased sports performance and increased risk of injury.

This image from [**pponline.co.uk**](http://www.pponline.co.uk/encyc/strength-training-overloading-to-increase-muscle-mass-40882) explains why you need some rest.
[image]

Making sure to workout when you're muscles are slightly stronger than before your workout will allow you to literally built up your muscles:
[image]

Comment: @에이바-I recently took two months off (competitive swimming) due to overtraining and three months later, I am forced to take yet more time off due to overtraining again. Do you think this is the same bout of overtraining, and that I just didn't recover from it fully the first time? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Overtraining, depending on the extent, can take weeks to years to recover from. I know of cases that recovered after 2-3 years. So most probably you did not recover from it the first time. Also, once you do recover, and can go back to practicing, there is a phase in which you should be very careful. You might be able to practice, but to get back to where you were before takes many years.

Comment: Now what is that time at after a bout where strength due to supercompensation is at its peak?

Answer (score 18):

Without rest, you will build muscle mass quicker than your supporting organs can build and adjust to enable their proper use. At that point, you will hit a plateau which you will be unable to cross. However, this does not hold true for aerobic exercise, where the [Mayo Clinic suggests 30 minutes daily](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/exercise/AN01713). This is more for muscle building and strength training.

Answer (score 8):

It has everything to do with the person. Top athletes train every day, and a lot of hours. Usually, they have spent some years making the body able to withstand a lot of training.

I was the fastest running youth in Norway some years back in 60-200m, and trained about 20 hours a week in the weeks with the most load. That was when between the age of 15 and 18. I had no problems with injuries, but again, this is often individually.

If someone wants to train everyday, like I do, the trick is to have **a lot variation** in the training. One simple example, just to easily show what I mean is this:

Monday: Running
Tuesday: Upper body weightlifting
Wednesday: Lower body weightlifting
Thursday: Mobility and stretching
Friday: Running
...

Answer (score 6):

[Supercompensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercompensation) would be some of the explanation if the goal is to get in better shape.

As I understand it: When the body rests it creates more muscle mass than what was actually destroyed during the exercise.

Answer (score 4):

I assume this depends on person, as well as speed and duration of the exercise.

Personally, after running few days in a row I get muscles tired: it feels like your legs are filled with lead. Not something you want before a big college competition.

But if you notice no changes in your body, I daresay it's ok. Walking is also an exercise and we do it daily without a problem.