# On smaller in between workout activies and the interpretation of resting phases

Tags: workout-routines, rest

I have a three days a week workout plan (weight lifting Mo,We,Fr, basically an arms/torso, shoulder, back split respecively, for an hour or more) and I do cardio in between (depending on the time of the year, running or dancing). I basically want to get in shape and generally feel healthier.

In the morning, I'd be motivated to do a short running around the house (8 mins or so) and then do some push-ups, crunches - a "30 minute workout before breakfast" so to speak.
Now I wonder if that might actually be counter productive or if it's good. The morning activities are quite light compared to weight lifting, say, but I'm not sure if e.g. resting phases for arms (which are supposed to be longer than a day) also imply I shouldn't do push-ups etc. daily.

Comment: The title is somewhat confusing…

Comment: what are your weightlifting and cardio programs? See this question on the importance of resting, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/96/3778

Comment: If your morning routine is focused on getting warmed up & loosened up, then great. If you are trying to work muscles that you just worked out hard the day before, then not-so-great.